# Group and rank top N rows by category

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the columns `category` and `votes`. I've tried multiple solutions before with very little success; usually what would happen is that instead of returning the top 3 items in each category, it returns all of the items available.

```
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `full_name`, `category`, `year`, `month`, `thumbnail_photo`, `photo_title`, `votes`
FROM
    (
    SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `full_name`, `category`, `year`, `month`, `thumbnail_photo`, `photo_title`, `votes`,
        @category_rank := IF(@current_category = category, @category_rank + 1, 1) AS category_rank,
        @current_category := category
    FROM `photo_contest`
    ORDER BY
        `category`,
        `votes` DESC
) ranked
WHERE
    category_rank <= 3
    AND `year` = '2017'
    AND `month` = 'April'
    AND `votes` > 0
```

This particular solution was adapted from [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group). What I ultimately want to do is to turn a table like this:

```
Name      | Category | Votes
--------- | -------- | -----
Name Foo  | CatFoo   | 0
Name Bar  | CatFoo   | 1
Name Baz  | CatFoo   | 10
Name Quux | CatFoo   | 200
Name ooF  | CatBar   | 50
Name raB  | CatBar   | 300
Name zaB  | CatBar   | 10
Name xuuQ | CatBar   | 200
```

...to:

```
Name      | Category | Votes
--------- | -------- | -----
Name Quux | CatFoo   | 200
Name Baz  | CatFoo   | 10
Name Bar  | CatFoo   | 1
Name raB  | CatBar   | 300
Name xuuQ | CatBar   | 200
Name ooF  | CatBar   | 50
```

...with the other WHERE statements included. Year, month, and minimum votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery tries to calculate ranking over the entire table. If you only want to rank for the selected year-month with votes > 0, you should copy those conditions into the subquery as its own WHERE conditions.

UPDATE:

Looks like it's the missing `ORDER BY` in the outer-query that causes the said problem. I've created the following DDL/SQL at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e66f3/9).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `year` VARCHAR(4) NULL,
  `month` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  `votes` INT
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `votes` VALUES
(10, 'cat1', '2016', '05', 300),
(10, 'cat1', '2016', '06', 200),
(10, 'cat2', '2016', '05', 500),
(11, 'cat1', '2016', '05', 200),
(11, 'cat2', '2016', '05', 0),
(11, 'cat2', '2016', '06', 100),
(12, 'cat1', '2016', '05', 400),
(12, 'cat2', '2016', '05', 150),
(13, 'cat1', '2016', '05', 350),
(13, 'cat2', '2016', '05', 100),
(13, 'cat2', '2016', '06', 150),
(14, 'cat1', '2016', '05', 0),
(14, 'cat2', '2016', '05', 450);

SELECT `id`, `category`, `year`, `month`, `votes`
FROM (
    SELECT `id`, `category`, `year`, `month`, `votes`,
        @category_rank := IF(@current_category = category, @category_rank + 1, 1) AS category_rank,
        @current_category := category
    FROM `votes`
    WHERE
        `year` = '2016'
        AND `month` = '05'
        AND `votes` > 0
    ORDER BY
        `category`,
        `votes` DESC
) ranked
WHERE
    category_rank <= 3
ORDER BY
    `category`,
    `votes` DESC;
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the query still returns more than 3 items from the same category. I also removed the WHERE statements from the main query as well.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Our dev server runs MySQL 5.6.35, perhaps there's an issue with that version that is resolved with 5.7+?

Comment: The sample code at `sqlfiddle` is also running with MySQL 5.6. Maybe it would help diagnosing if you could show your output (with WHERE conditions in subquery and ORDER BY in outer-query).

Comment: @Mark, your subquery doesn't have the `ORDER BY` necessary for proper ranking. I've revised the SQL at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04ea84/4).

Comment: I've tried that, and still getting the extra rows. I did check our PHPMyAdmin installation and it says that the version of the PHP extension (5.1) doesn't match the installed version (5.6).

Comment: @Mark, just to confirm, are you seeing the SQL as in my latest [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04ea84/4) link working? Are you able to get correct result by running the same SQL using a native MySQL client? If the same SQL that works with the MySQL server doesn't work in the PHP client application, it's now a different issue.

Comment: I've checked using the SQL above in PHPMyAdmin (SQLFiddle seems to be pretty finicky and doesn't want to load), and I get an [incorrect list](http://imgur.com/a/mkjwq). I've rechecked the server page and it definitely says that the libmysql version is 5.1.73 with the server being 5.6.35.

Comment: @Mark, please see my response in a separate answer.

Comment: Tried this, and doesn't seem to work, it returns 0 rows. SQL generated from code: https://paste.ee/p/ltzyX

Comment: A pretty late response, but I ultimately split it up into two 1+n queries: First query is for selecting the current distinct categories based on the current month and year (as the year, month, and category were originally inserted as plain text by the original coder, so I couldn't change that without really rebuilding all of the "mini-application") and then looping through each category to get the latest 3 rows from each category. Eventually it'll be replaced with its own separate solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with MySQL, so I propose you a different (standard SQL) approach: you can join the table with itself on `Category` and on `Votes` being less or equal to the votes of the current row.

```
select  t1.Name, t1.Category, t1.Votes, count(distinct t2.Name) as rank
from    photo_contest t1
join    photo_contest t2
on      t1.Category = t2.Category and
        t1.Votes <= t2.Votes
/*where whatever you want*/
group by t1.Name, t1.Category, t1.Votes
having  count(distinct t2.Name) <= 3
order by t1.Category, rank
```

I tested it [here](http://rextester.com/GQTM1215) and it seems to do what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your PHPMyAdmin needs an upgrade or a replacement. Meanwhile you might want to try @Stefano Zanini's non-MySQL specific SQL:

```
SELECT
    t1.`id`, t1.`category`, t1.`year`, t1.`month`,
    t1.`votes`, count(distinct t2.`id`) as rank
FROM photo_contest t1
INNER JOIN photo_contest t2 ON
    t1.`category` = t2.`category` AND
    t1.`votes` <= t2.`votes`
WHERE t1.`votes` > 0
GROUP BY t1.`id`, t1.`category`, t1.`votes`
HAVING count(distinct t2.`id`) <= 3
ORDER BY t1.`category`, rank;
```

It's available on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04ea84/8). If you think this solution suits you better please credit @Stefano Zanini's answer instead of this one.

Comment: I didn't notice this until now. I'll take a look tomorrow morning and see if it works. The project that I'm using it in is most likely going to go live(!).

Comment: I tried this, and it returns nothing. This is the SQL outputted from the CMS/framework that I am using: https://paste.ee/p/ltzyX